# How to have Android automatically add commas?

Tags: java, android

```
String number = textView1.getText().toString();
double amount = Double.parseDouble(number);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
String formatted = formatter.format(amount);

textView1.setText(formatted);
```

I'm using this code to have it add commas to a textview in my application. But when I run my app it does absolutely nothing? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by it does absolutely nothing?

Comment: I run the app. And the number just looks like: 123456789 - no commas

Comment: What happens when you log the String?

Comment: Log.v("Decimal String", formatted);

Comment: 08-28 18:21:28.533: V/Decimal String(804): 0

Comment: Are u doing that in a ActionPerformed? If you want to auto-format text while typing you should implement a EditorListener at the EditText

Comment: Well I put it in my onCreate method just to see if it would do anything before i put it elsewhere. And it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I tested a bit around and I got the solution.

```
String in = "123456789";            
double amount = Double.parseDouble(in);         
amount = amount / 10;       
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".00");        
String formatted = df.format(amount);           
System.out.println(formatted);
```

==>> output is here: 12345678,90
you have to divide your double to get your comma.

The double you get with your version is 123456789.00 --> by dividing it by 10 .. or whatever you like it gets 12345678.90 ... in that case a simple

```
String.valueOf(amount);
```

would be sufficient. But if you change the DecimalFormat to

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(",###.00");
```

your output is ==> 12.345.678,90

Comment: Didn't do anything. :(

Comment: Oh sry ... i got this ..... you parse it as double ... so your new value is (String --> "1234" --> 1234.0) so there is a '.'

Comment: Changed it in my edit, but still no luck? In the Logcat it changed to "000.00"